# Want to replace string in js

Tags: javascript

I want to replace ^ to ** in js but we try to use str.replace it only replaces a first one and rest string are same

```
 const input = "2^3+4^4";
    const replace = input.replace("^", "**");
    console.log(replace);
```

output :

```
2**3+4^4
```

but i want

```
2**3+4**4
```

Comment: replaceAll() method ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex like this:

```
const input = "2^3+4^4";
const replace = input.replace(/\^/g, "**");
console.log(replace);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex with flag `g` which make the regex don't stop to the first occurrence.

```js
const input = '2^3+4^4';

const replace = input.replace(/\^/g, '**');

console.log(replace); // output: 2**3+4**4
```

Answer (score 0):

const replace = input.replace(/^/g, "**");

Comment: Won't work, this will simply prepend "**" to any given string. Besides that, please, make a minimal snippet or at least mark your code as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const input = "2^3+4^4";
const replace = input.replace(/\^/g, "**");
console.log(replace);
```

The **/g** means it's "global" replacement.

Answer (score 0):

const replace = input.split("^").join("**")

Comment: Please, make a minimal snippet or at least mark your code as code.